# Increase efficiency of bash loop with awk

Tags: bash, speed, awk

I have to write a fairly large text file(>300,000 lines) using text extracted from the second column of one file, then prepending and appending text to each line and finally writing it out to a new file.

I have the following while loop and it is working fine. But it is slow, taking many minutes per run. I suspect that there is a better awk recipe/method that would be much faster. Can anyone suggest a faster method.

SOURCEFILE example

```
useless9   important1   more useless stuff
useless8   important2   more useless stuff
useless7   important3   more useless stuff
useless6   important4   more useless stuff
```

Extract text from source file and output final result file.

```
while read line; do

  mytext=`echo $line | awk -v RS='\r\n' '{print $2}'`

  echo "$PrePattern $mytext $PostPattern" >> $OUTFILE

done < $SOURCEFILE
```

OUTFILE

```
PrePattern text important1 PostPattern text
PrePattern text important2 PostPattern text
PrePattern text important3 PostPattern text
...
```

Comment: show some sample lines from the source file. That whole loop can probably be expressed as `awk -v pre="$PrePattern" -v post="$PostPattern" '{print pre, $2, post}' "$SOURCEFILE"`

Comment: Thanks very much, glen jackman! As I suspected there was a performance gain to be had. Your solution just turned a ~15 minute process into ~3 seconds

Comment: much of that gain is not having to launch 300,000 awk processes, when just 1 will do

Answer (score 1):

You need to study awk more.

```
awk '{print "prepattern mytext "$2" postpattern";}' <$sourcefile >$outfile
```

Comment: Can you start that education process by explaining what this does?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 Well instead of that, go read the awk man page and then look at the example I posted. After that if you have specific questions, I'll help you understand those points.